# Flask + IIS + Motion JPEG

Tags: python, flask, iis, cgi, mjpeg

I'm trying to accomplish the following:
1. capture a live-stream = done using screen-capture (mss package)
2. recognize faces in 1) = done using "face_recognition" package
3. (re-)stream the results as Motion-JPEG with the recognised faces in a web application hosted in Flask + IIS = problems

So, when I stream the result only to Flask using the debug functionality (flask run --debugger), it works (picture on the right --> see http://127.0.0.1:....). BUT, when I try to use IIS, it doesn't work, resulting a gray image (picture below) - see http://193.....

[image]

I know for sure that IIS works with Flask because I already have some web-services hosted in the same application.

FLASK:

```
@app.route('/py/bbb', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bbb():
    return render_template("bbb.html")

@app.route('/py/video_feed', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def video_feed():

    imagineProcesata = screenrec.proceseazaImagine()

    return Response(imagineProcesata, mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Python:

```
def proceseazaImagine():
[.....]
            predictions = recunoaste_fetze(face_unknown)

            face_unknown = show_prediction_labels_on_image(face_unknown, predictions)

            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', face_unknown)

            jpeg2 = jpeg.tobytes()

            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + bytearray(jpeg2) + b'\r\n\r\n')
```

HTML Template:

```
  <head>
    <title>Video Streaming din BBwwB</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Streaming din BBBeee</h1>
    <img id="bg" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" />
  </body>
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
  <handlers>   
   <add name="Python FastCGI" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\opencv\python.exe|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FlaskRedirect\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
  </handlers>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
<appSettings>
  <!-- Required settings -->
  <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.app" />
  <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FlaskRedirect" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set application pool identity to local system? Besides, did you see any exception in developer tool console tabe or event viewer?

Comment: I enabled logging to debug something and it's quite strange...and it appears to be from the permissions granted to IIS / application pool somehow - when I run "flask run" I get the screen-shots emitted to files, but when I run the app from IIS I get some black and very low size image...

Comment: Could you fix it by changing app pool identity to local system?

Comment: no, apparently it does not work. I even tried to allow the service to "interact with desktop". after more research I found another approach, using ZMQ protocol: a client to grab continously screenshots, they would be sent to a server for processing, both using "ImageZMQ". Then another http-based application to get processed imaged from the server and then pushed to the browser using motion-jpeg. 

Something like this: https://github.com/jeffbass/imagezmq/blob/master/docs/advanced-pub-sub.rst

Comment: If you have another approach, I'm willing to listen.